# Is '\n' really used for flushing?

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (){

    while(1){
        fprintf (stdout,"hello-out");
        fprintf (stderr,"hello-err");
        sleep (1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Well i thought this would simply print, hello-out then hello-err take one second rest and print those literals again, but no, something weird is going on, it just prints hello-err then takes one second rest and does the same thing again. WHY?

But wait, i then decided to print them on separate lines and now it worked.

```
fprintf (stdout,"hello-out\n");
fprintf (stderr,"hello-err\n");
```

---------- same as ------------

```
fprintf (stdout,"hello-out\n");
fprintf (stderr,"hello-err");
```

So what is the importance of '\n' here? Is this related to flushing?
Because i read that '\n' is used for flushing.

And also printing both the literals on stdout, doesn't produce any output :(

```
fprintf (stdout,"hello-out");
fprintf (stdout,"hello-err");
```

again WHY?

Comment: Don't try to convert your code to HTML; paste the actual code, highlight it, and click the `{}` button.

Comment: \n is not used for flushing, it's used to place a carriage return in the output. It just happens that on a buffered output path, \n will flush the buffer. You can also flush it explicitly, using the `fflush()` function.

Answer (score 11):

By default, `stdout` is line buffered.  This means that unless you explicitly flush it, there is no guarantee when your writes will be written through to their destination until it sees a `\n`.

`stderr` on the other hand, is unbuffered by default. Every write will be written through immediately.

Comment: Oh so i guessed it right, thank you very much. Have a great day.

Comment: `stdout` is only line buffered if it is known to be tied to an interactive device. Otherwise, it's fully buffered. So you may not "see" it even after newline if it's redirected to a file (that you're tailing, for example).

Answer (score 1):

i have changed your code this way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (){
int i;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    fprintf (stdout,"hello-out");
    fprintf (stderr,"hello-err");
    sleep (1);
}

return 0;
}
```

Now output is

```
hello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-errhello-out
hello-outhello-outhello-outhello-out
```

as stderr is not buffered so its prints as it comes. but stdout is line buffered so it print when \n comes or when your code terminates or anytime...so in the end i see stdout prints

Answer (score -3):

No, this is not used for flushing. fflush is used for this. \n simply indicates a newline.